# Заблокировать один input по Radio button и получить его значение (php, bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html

Задача:
Пользователь должен выбрать значение из готового выпадающего списка либо добавить его вручную
У меня два input сгруппированных с radiobutton (список и поле ввода)
При выборе одного из вариантов, нужно получить его значение, второй должен становиться неактивным (disabled).

Как это реализовать?

```html
<form method="POST">
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-text">
    <input class="form-check-input mt-0" type="radio" value="" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
</div>
<div>Или этот вариант</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-text">
    <input class="form-check-input mt-0" type="radio" value="" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
  </div>
 <select name="pick_tab_nomer"  class="form-control" placeholder="Выберите ТАБ №" required autofocus>
    <option value="0">Не выбран</OPTION>
    <option value="1">Значение 1</OPTION>
    <option value="2">Значение 2</OPTION>
</select> 
<button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: РНР находится **на сервере**. Пользователь взаимодействует с **браузером** на своем компьютере. В браузере никакого РНР **нет.** Очень большая просьба выучить это простое, но важное различие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> второй должен становиться неактивным (disabled).

Можно пойти другим путём и присвоить одинаковый `name` обеим `input[type="radio"]` для возможности выбора лишь одного из двух.

```html
<form method="POST">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-text">
      <input class="form-check-input mt-0" name="radioButton" type="radio" value="" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
  </div>
  <div>Или этот вариант</div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-text">
      <input class="form-check-input mt-0" name="radioButton" type="radio" value="" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
    </div>
    <select name="pick_tab_nomer" class="form-control" placeholder="Выберите ТАБ №" required autofocus>
      <option value="0">Не выбран</OPTION>
      <option value="1">Значение 1</OPTION>
      <option value="2">Значение 2</OPTION>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```